# Vim bracket and semicolon highliting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes vim highlights brackets or semicolon with red color. What plugin highlights it? Does it mean error in this place? Look on a picture please.

[image]

Comment: Is that SASS or SCSS? Do you use a dedicated syntax file for it? The default CSS syntax file would consider your code as borked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the default syntax highlighter, it means that vim has flagged something wrong with that location. Check out `:help syntax` for more options. As @romainl stated, other plugins may be affecting what you see.

I have a vanilla Cygwin version running and it flags a few brackets in your css snippet as being invalid either due to missing opening/closing brackets or bad syntax as vim defines it.

Comment: If the code above is in fact supposed to be CSS, it is full of errors: `&` is not a valid tag name in HTML and there's no nesting possible in CSS. *If this code is supposed to be CSS* @user1798349 should fix it before going further.

Comment: it is scss. when i installed scss-syntax plugin and added   au BufRead,BufNewFile *.scss set filetype=scss in vimrc but nothing changed. I think vim opens scss files as css.

Comment: Did you [copy the syntax file](https://github.com/cakebaker/scss-syntax.vim) to the proper location?

Comment: Yeah. I also tried to kill all my plugins but i still have red highlight bracket

Comment: Check `:set filetype` and ensure that it is actually set to scss. If not, forcing it with `:set filetype=scss` may be worth trying. You can also do `:syntax list` and see if the listing looks like it actually loaded your scss syntax rules, or if they are just the base css rules.

Comment: :set filetype says "scss". I deleted all text from vimrc except "syntax on" and also deleted all my plugins. I still have this red bracket.

Comment: I don't know scss; are you sure you have a valid file? Seems like everything is telling you that you have a syntax error.

Comment: the problem is in & symbol. When i replace it with selector no errors found.
but the syntax is right.
 `a {
  color: #ce4dd6;
  &:hover { color: #ffb3ff; }
  &:visited { color: #c458cb; }
}`

Comment: I have the same problem with my scss files, as far as I can tell the problems are stemming from the vim css syntax rules but I can't confirm that.